# iOS AFnetworking NSURLSessionDataTask with sleep

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, afnetworking

I am working with AFNetworking Get method. I have one API where my server uses sleep due to some functionality. whenever  I call this API all other API stuck and connection time out. Once I kill the application no other API will call till my server response to that API. to resolve that error I have used below code after call that API,

```
let cookie = HTTPCookie.self
    let cookieJar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared

    for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! {
        print(cookie.name+"="+cookie.value)
        cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
```

If I delete cookie it working fine, I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: It looks like the problem is on the server side.

Comment: What kind of the problem, did you know that? This API work fine in android version , They use OKHTTP